# Is there anyway to keep existing wordpress posts updated when Google sheet is updated

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, custom-fields, zapier

We are looking to build a fully automated wordpress website.

The websites posts take there information from Google sheets.

We need to link the wordpress posts data and advanced custom fields to a Google sheet that will update in real time.

I know there is a zapier function that will create new wordpress post on new google sheet row creation.

But we are wondering is there a way to update existing posts when existing Google sheet row has been updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using Zapier. I created a Google Sheet with my data. The connected Sheets to Wordpress. So if i need to make a change to a Wordpress page or post, I just update the Google Sheet.